# Is there a difference between Google Nest Mini and Google Nest Mini 2nd gen?

Tags: smart-home, google-home

I'm looking to dive into home automation starting from a `Google Nest Mini` device. 
I understand that there has been a `Home Mini` and then the second iteration was rebranded as `Nest`. But a retailer site [recommended by Google India](https://store.google.com/in/magazine/retailers_google_nest_mini) has two generations of Google Nest Minis with two different prices - [Nest Mini](https://www.tatacliq.com/google-nest-mini-chalk/p-mp000000006446830) and [Nest Mini (2nd Gen)](https://www.tatacliq.com/google-nest-mini-2nd-gen--chalk/p-mp000000005976505). Also, they do [list Home Mini](https://www.tatacliq.com/google-home-mini-chalk/p-mp000000002964941) separately.
I cannot figure out the difference between Nest Mini and Nest Mini 2nd gen. Every article/video I read/watch compares `Nest` with `Home` without suggesting that there's a 2nd Gen Nest Mini.

If there's, I'd love to be directed towards a link where I can understand the difference. I'm very confused. 
TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Nest_(smart_speakers)#Model_comparison) the rebranded one is the 2nd Generation one. So there's just a Home Mini (1st gen) and a Nest Mini (2nd gen) but nothing in between. I also know from my colleagues at work who are doing integration with these products that they only have those two types of Minis. On the page there are also the differences between the two. Seems your retailer there was a bit lazy in putting the correct names on these products.